# Laravel - Route com variavel

Tags: php, laravel, mvc

Bom dia Senhores. Estou com uma dúvida quanto ao route no Laravel, realizei pesquisas tentando achar o resultado mas não achei o que eu queria.

Preciso que a partir do id que for redirecionado (por exemplo: /disciplina/3) ele mande o número "3" para o parâmetro do meu metodo retorna_disciplina($id) para eu poder trabalhar com ele.
Tentei fazer como abaixo mas nada deu certo até o momento. O que devo fazer?

Obrigado

Código no arquivo web.php

```
Route::get('/disciplina/{id}', "select@retorna_disciplina(id)")->middleware('login');
```

Código no controller

```
 public function retorna_disciplina($id)
    {
        $prontuario = session('prontuario');
        $cargo = session('cargo');

        if($cargo == "P")
        {
            $disciplina = DB::table('oferecimento_disciplina')
                ->where('id_professor','=', $prontuario)
                ->where('dsa', '=', $id)
                ->first();

            if(count($disciplina)>0)
            {
                $postagens = DB::table('postagens')
                    ->where('dsa', '=', $id)
                    ->get();
                return view('disciplinas.disciplina')->with([
                        'disciplina' => $disciplina,
                        'postagens' => $postagens
                    ]);
            }
            else{
                Redirect::to('/perfil')->withErros("A disciplina não existe ou você não tem permissão de acesso");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Qual é a versão do seu Laravel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sua Route tem um pequeno erro, deve ser assim (presumo que o nome do controllador e do ficheiro respetivo esteja certo e seja "select"):

```
Route::get('/disciplina/{id}', "select@retorna_disciplina")->middleware('login');
```

No controlador deve ter:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request; // caso não tenha já isto, deve estar no topo ao lado dos outros "use" que deve ter
...
public function retorna_disciplina(Request $request) {
    $id = $request->id;
    ....
}
```

A variável `$request`, armazena a informação acerca da requisição, em que parte dela são o parametros enviados via `GET`, neste caso o id.

Comment: Tem certeza? `$request->id` funciona? Geralmente,  passa-se o valor `$id` como parâmetro, e o mesmo é capturado...

Comment: Foi sempre assim que fiz @WallaceMaxters, pelo menos também funciona

Comment: Olha minha resposta. Desde a versão 4 do Laravel, sempre utilizei o parâmetro no método. Acho que talvez seja porque os tutoriais da documentação só ensinava a fazer assim. É a primeira vez que vejo isso aí.

Comment: Eu acho que assim acaba por ser melhor, porque tem acesso a mais informações acerca da requisição, ex: `$request->ip`, `$request->url()` etc... E está mais à mão, pelo menos sempre fiz assim @WallaceMaxters

Comment: Perfeito, fiz conforme mencionou e me ajudou muito! Obrigado mais uma vez Miguel.

Comment: Olá, de nada @RenanKaicLopes, ainda bem que resolveu

Answer (score 2):

Você só precisa especificar na expressão da sua rota qual o parâmetro que será variável na url. Em seguida, no seu controller, você define o parâmetro desejado para capturar o parâmetro da url no seu método específico.

Veja o exemplo abaixo.

Controller:

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
      public function getArticle($id)
      {
         dd($id);
      }
}
```

Rota:

```
Route::get('site/article/{id}', 'SiteController@getArticle');
```

No caso acima, ao você chamar a rota `site/article/5`, o parâmetro `$id` do método `getArticle` terá o valor  `5`.

Observe que, para indicar qual trecho da url terá o parâmetro variável, você precisa usar uma palavra envolvida por chaves `{}`.

Caso seja necessário usar `Request` no seu método, você pode fazer assim:

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
      public function getArticle(Request $request, $id)
      {
         dd($id);
      }
}
```

Comment: Desta maneira nunca fiz, mas também instancia o `Request` tem acesso a todas as informações na mesma, mas escusa de colocar outro argumento

Comment: @Miguel geralmente, para acessar `$request->id`, só quando passo `/article/?id=5` na url. Daquela forma ali foi diferente, não tinha visto ainda. Não sabia que o Laravel "misturava" requisições com o parâmetro da rota.

Comment: O parametro da rota também faz parte da requisição (GET), faz sentido que tenha acesso a ele a partir dela

Comment: @Miguel na verdade, não faz não. O `path` da url não tem nada a ver com a `query string`. Foi por isso que eu  achei estranho o Laravel fazer isso. Não estou dizendo que a resposta está errada, só estou dizendo que não sabia que funcionava.

Comment: Wallace tenho mesmo a ideia que faz, eu imagino que quando laravel 'vê' uma rota com `/user/{id}` parta do príncipio que o `id` vai ser um parametro enviado via GET e dinâmico. Que em bruto seria `user?id=1`